# Correct approach using t-test and Wilcoxon rank sum test?

Tags: t-test, normality-assumption, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I want to compare 2 datasets.

I have a biological structure A with its atom coordinates which are a few thousands. I also have from these atom coordinates the coordinates over time of about 20 nanoseconds. 
From this structure A I made about 70 simulations. After the simulation I calculated the distance between atoms within this structure and afterwards the average distance of these 70 simulations for each time step which means that I finally have the average distance of 20 nanoseconds of the structures A.

Now I also have a structure B with which I made 80 simulations and performed the same procedure as described above.

Finally I want to compare the average distance over time of structure A and structure B.

1) I make a Shapiro-Wilk or Shapiro-Francia test to make sure that the data has a normal distribution

2) If the data is normally distributed I use a t-test, otherwise a Wilcoxon rank sum test

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: Atom coordinates are multidimensional, right? x,y,z plus type? What specific aspect of the coordinates do you want to test? Absolute distance from a point, per atom?

Comment: yeah, i have x,y,z values. I want to compare the average structure A and the structure B. No distance calculations. Just, how "similiar" they are by using t-test or wilcoxon.

Comment: So what *dependent variable*/outcome do you want to run the test on? The *t*-test is an univariate test - it compares one or two groups of numbers of one kind. Of course, you can't compare x-axis values to y-axis values. If you want to compare 3-dimensional coordinate points, you might need another kind of test.

Comment: i am sorry jona. I did a mistake. i ve calculated the distance in a structure A over time. And also the distance in a structure B. Now i want to compare the values. thx for your help :-)

Comment: Are A and B values paired?

Comment: no they are not paired

Answer (score 2):

Edited: "In large samples, the t-test is not especially sensitive to non-normal data." So the question you need to answer is whether your data are [independently and identically distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) and use the *t* test if interested in "average distance".

Comment: The numerator is a *sample mean*, it's not the data. And I used the term *asymptotically normal* as shorthand for "t-distributed which is an approximately normal distribution, which is asymptotically normal", which is hand-wavy, I'll grant you.

Comment: OK, I appreciate the insight on chat (I can't get chat to work on my system, and the test/troubleshoot page hasn't helped). I'll leave this comment here a few minutes then edit my answer.

Comment: No need to acknowledge me, assuming you don't disagree with the sentiment. If you'd rather it say something else, of course you should do so.

Answer (score 1):

(i) Since measured values over time will often tend to be correlated, you shouldn't assume independence without good reason.

(ii) if your real interest is in 'how similar they are' a hypothesis test *will not answer that question* - it answers an entirely different question

(iii) the goodness of fit test *also* answers the wrong question. If you're trying to decide how much the normality assumption could affect your inference, you should address *that* question.

The two-stage procedure "test for normality and if it's not rejected use normal theory procedures otherwise use something that doesn't assume normality" is not a good strategy. It has the problem that neither of the second stage tests has the nominal properties. That is you don't get the significance level and power characteristics you get when you don't choose which to do based on the outcome of the first stage test. If some procedure is acceptable to you when you don't have normality, and it performs reasonably when you do (like the Wilcoxon, which has very high ARE), there's no reason to avoid it if you're not reasonably confident of normality. If the slight loss in power does concern you, why not go to a permutation (/randomization) test instead?

[On the other hand, in large samples, a t-test may not be very badly affected by an amount of non-normality that is easy to detect, so it may be perfectly reasonable. Since you can simulate data, you have the ability to assess the impact of similar non-normality.]

Comment: first, thx for your effort glen_b
(ii+iii) the point is that i want to make 100 statistical tests for different structures which are calculated by the computer automatically. thats why i wanted to use a test for checking the distribution and based on that using the optimal test.
if i understand that correctly you propose me to use only the Wilcoxon test or permutation test. But if i use the wilcoxon test the samples must have the same median, right? Therefore i still need another test for the case the median is different?
BTW: if you know a good book about statistics then please let me know

Comment: i ve read in a book now that a t-test for samples with a size above n>=30 shouldnt be a problem. As i use for my calculations n=3000 i still could use the t-test, right? i know u mentioned it below of your posting but may be u still have someting to consider. thx you :-)

Comment: +1 I agree with one interpretation of "not a good strategy" but disagree with another which, although likely not intended, might be what readers come away with. A correct (IMHO) interpretation is that preliminary normality testing *without adjusting subsequent p-values* can be mistaken. The erroneous interpretation is that such preliminary screening should never be done. I would like to suggest that some such two-step strategy makes a lot of sense, especially for wholesale computer screening, *provided* the p-values are correctly adjusted (both for the two steps and the multiple comparisons).

Comment: @whuber the problem isn't simply one of p-values. First, for both normality testing and heteroskedasticity testing with subsequent test choice (t vs WMW and t vs Welch-t respectively), it has been shown that performance was substantially affected (significance, power, and in some cases test bias, IIRC), and substantially worse than simply not assuming the stronger condition (I'll have to see if I can locate one of the references again). ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... Second, from a logical consistency point of view, the testing simply answers the wrong question. The question is something along the lines of "which test would be better", which could be answered by formulating that decision problem; a normality test doesn't come close to responding to that question. Indeed, because normality is relatively "hard" to test for, you tend to lack power against non-normality in the only situation where it matters, and you finally attain some power against non-normality when it matters less. ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... if (akin to your suggestion) one takes proper consideration of the properties of the overall procedure, it may well be possible to have something which doesn't have worse properties than just doing WMW (I'd think one could beat it) - but in practice I've never seen anyone do it; given the power loss in using WMW even in fairly small samples at the normal tends to be modest, the simple advice "just use WMW" would be prudent unless we have specific alternatives to offer people who won't actually do the necessary work to make the more complex approach a competitive alternative to it.

Comment: Those are good points about the overall test performance: after achieving a correct p-value, one does need to conduct a power study. Your "prudent" advice looks good except when sample sizes are small and cannot be enlarged, for then the issue is whether we should accept that WMW has virtually no power or try to gain more power in return for committing to a parametric assumption. In at least one arena (environmental compliance), there is a strong prior belief that the underlying data are either normal or lognormal, so perhaps a Bayesian analysis could provide some guidance.